# Angular/flex-layout, how to add vertical space between rows when using fxLayout="row wrap"?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I wrote code like this:

```html
    <div fxLayout="row wrap"
         fxLayoutGap="20px"
         fxLayoutAlign="flex-start">
      <mat-card fxFlex="0 1 calc(33.3% - 20px)"
        class="my-card"
        *ngFor="let item of items">
        ...
      </mat-card>
    </div>
```

It looks pretty good, only that there is no space between rows. How to add vertical gap between rows using Angular flex-layout and material UI libraries (mat-card here)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use grid mode:
[FlexLayout Grid Mode](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxLayoutGap-API#grid-mode)
`fxLayoutGap="10px grid"`

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any out-of-box fx- directives for this. Ended up with this solution, which works, but may not be the most elegant solution. In this css file, simply add:

```css
.my-card {
  ...
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  ...
}
```